# use of _block variable in ios7

Tags: ios7

i use this code for assigning value to varible in block i am using ios7 xcode5 its not working for me.

```
_Block NSString *temp=Nil;    
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f delay:0.03f usingSpringWithDamping:30.0f initialSpringVelocity:30.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        [vwBottomMain setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, vwBottomMain.frame.origin.y-39, vwBottomMain.frame.size.width,vwBottomMain.frame.size.height)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
       temp=@"test";
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you don't show the rest of this method, the most likely problem is that your completion handler is asynchronous but you're expecting results immediately.

Try running the following code to see what order things are happening in.  It should demonstrate that the assignment happens after the test.

```
__block NSString *temp = nil;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f delay:0.03f usingSpringWithDamping:30.0f initialSpringVelocity:30.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
    NSLog(@"Animation section");
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"Completion handler");
    temp = @"test";
}];
NSLog(@"String test %@", temp);
```